# Git - squashing earlier commits and reflecting it on different branches

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to Git and I'm trying to squash a series of earlier commits, but I'm having problems having this 'squashing' reflect on all branches.

I started with the following tree:

```
A---->B---->C---->D---->E---->F---->G---->H (Branch 1)
                                          \
                                           \
                                            \
                                             I---->J---->K (Branch 2)
```

I want to 'squash' commits C, D, E and F, but I want this 'squashing' to be reflected on both Branches 1 and 2.

I tried `'git rebase -i HEAD~7'` and did the necessary changes (while on Branch 1), but this is what I ended with:

```
A---->B---->C'---->G---->H (Branch 1)
      \
       \
        \
         C---->D---->E---->F---->G---->H---->I---->J---->K (Branch 2)
```

When what I wanted to get was:

```
A---->B---->C'---->G---->H (Branch 1)
                          \
                           \
                            \
                             I---->J---->K (Branch 2)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to achieve the result I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An easy solution would be to create a 3rd branch at H on Branch 1 after having done the `rebase` above. Then `cherry-pick` `I`, `J`, and `K` onto this branch. Then delete branch 2 and rename the new branch the same as your old branch 2

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `cherry-pick` but after a quick check on the docs this worked exactly as expected. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: No problem. But I have a better answer on the way

Comment: Remember that it won't be `G` and `H` on that rebased branch 1, but a new `G'` and `H'` with different commit IDs.

Comment: @cmbuckley you are right and that's an important note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is better than the `cherry-pick` answer in my comment because if you have a lot of commits to `cherry-pick` that can be rather tedious (it also avoids the creation of a third branch).

The quickest thing to do is two `rebase`s. The first is the one you specified. Then you `checkout` branch 2 and rebase that on top of your already-`rebase`d branch 1, removing the commits you don't want (`C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, and `H`). So basically, you'd have:

```
git checkout <branch 1>
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

which you already did, followed by:

```
git checkout <branch 2>
git rebase -i <branch 1>
```

When your default editor opens, simply remove the lines associated with commits `C` through `H`. The result will be what you were looking for.

Comment: You could also just use `git rebase --onto branch1 H` for your final command, which means "take all commits on this current branch after `H` and replay them on top of branch1."

Comment: Also works as expected. It took me a while to understand exactly how the second `rebase` worked, but once I figured it out it was definitely a more elegant solution!